# Grading Logic for a Simple Quiz App

Tags: java, android

I'm making a simple quiz app and I can't get the grading logic right.
I have 5 questions with 6 checkboxes each and each question has 2 correct answers out of the 6 checkboxes. I want to make it so that the grading logic marks the answer as correct: (something like this:)

```
if (ALL_RIGHT_CHOICES_ARE_CHECKED && ALL_OTHERS_ARE_NOT_CHECKED) {
+=1}
```

without limiting the checkbox selection (since I don't get that concept yet). How do I make it happen? This is my current code:

```
package com.example.android.architecturequizapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

//method called when Submit&Grade button is clicked
public void submitAnswers(View view) {

    //EditText name
    EditText nameTypeTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_edit_text);
    String typeName = nameTypeTextBox.getText().toString();

    //Question 1: Name Question: Eiffel Tower
    RadioButton q1Name = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.q1_eiffel_tower_radio_button);
    boolean hasQ1NameCorrect = q1Name.isChecked();

    //Question 1: Location Question: Paris
    CheckBox q1Location1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q1_paris_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ1Location1Correct = q1Location1.isChecked();

    //Question 1: Location Question: France
    CheckBox q1Location2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q1_france_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ1Location2Correct = q1Location2.isChecked();

    //Question 2: Name Question: Colosseum
    RadioButton q2Name = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.q2_colosseum_radio_button);
    boolean hasQ2NameCorrect = q2Name.isChecked();

    //Question 2: Location Question: Rome
    CheckBox q2Location1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q2_rome_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ2Location1Correct = q2Location1.isChecked();

    //Question 2: Location Question: Italy
    CheckBox q2Location2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q2_italy_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ2Location2Correct = q2Location2.isChecked();

    //Question 3: Name Question: Tower of Pisa
    RadioButton q3Name = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.q3_tower_of_pisa_radio_button);
    boolean hasQ3NameCorrect = q3Name.isChecked();

    //Question 3: Location Question: Pisa
    CheckBox q3Location1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q3_pisa_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ3Location1Correct = q3Location1.isChecked();

    //Question 3: Location Question: Italy
    CheckBox q3Location2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q3_italy_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ3Location2Correct = q3Location2.isChecked();

    //Question 4: Name Question: Casa Batllo
    RadioButton q4Name = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.q4_casa_batllo_radio_button);
    boolean hasQ4NameCorrect = q4Name.isChecked();

    //Question 4: Location Question: Barcelona
    CheckBox q4Location1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q4_barcelona_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ4Location1Correct = q4Location1.isChecked();

    //Question 4: Location Question: Spain
    CheckBox q4Location2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q4_spain_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ4Location2Correct = q4Location2.isChecked();

    //Question 5: Name Question: Eiffel Tower
    RadioButton q5Name = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.q5_opera_house_radio_button);
    boolean hasQ5NameCorrect = q5Name.isChecked();

    //Question 5: Location Question: Sydney
    CheckBox q5Location1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q5_sydney_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ5Location1Correct = q5Location1.isChecked();

    //Question 5: Location Question: Australia
    CheckBox q5Location2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q5_australia_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ5Location2Correct = q5Location2.isChecked();

    int questionsCorrect = calculateRightAnswers(hasQ1NameCorrect, hasQ1Location1Correct, hasQ1Location2Correct, hasQ2NameCorrect, hasQ2Location1Correct, hasQ2Location2Correct, hasQ3NameCorrect, hasQ3Location1Correct, hasQ3Location2Correct, hasQ4NameCorrect, hasQ4Location1Correct, hasQ4Location2Correct, hasQ5NameCorrect, hasQ5Location1Correct, hasQ5Location2Correct);

    //toast message for questions correct/score
    //less than 5 = poor results
    if (questionsCorrect <= 5) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Poor results! You scored " + questionsCorrect + "/15!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    } else if (questionsCorrect <= 10) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Average results! You scored " + questionsCorrect + "/15!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    } else if (questionsCorrect <= 14) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Good results! You scored " + questionsCorrect + "/15!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    } else {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Excellent! You scored " + questionsCorrect + "/15!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }

    //TextView message on bottom
    endQuiz(typeName);

}

//calculate total points scored on quiz
private int calculateRightAnswers(boolean q1Name, boolean q1Location1, boolean q1Location2, boolean q2Name, boolean q2Location1, boolean q2Location2, boolean q3Name, boolean q3Location1, boolean q3Location2, boolean q4Name, boolean q4Location1, boolean q4Location2, boolean q5Name, boolean q5Location1, boolean q5Location2) {
    //score before taking quiz
    int pointsScored = 0;

    //1 part of Q1 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q1Name) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q1 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q1Location1) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q1 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q1Location2) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q2 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q2Name) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q2 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q2Location1) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q2 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q2Location2) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q3 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q3Name) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q3 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q3Location1) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q3 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q3Location2) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q4 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q4Name) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q4 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q4Location1) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q4 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q4Location2) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q5 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q5Name) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q5 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q5Location1) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q5 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q5Location2) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    return pointsScored;
}

private String endQuiz(String nameTyped) {
    TextView endingMessageTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ending_message_text_view);
    String endQuizMessage = "Thank you " + nameTyped + " for completing the quiz!";
    endQuizMessage += "\nHope you enjoyed it!";
    endingMessageTextView.setText(endQuizMessage);
    return endQuizMessage;
}
}
```

Could anyone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Include your layout xml

Comment: @dltidud0108 Added some rough code let us know if you need more help

Comment: @ditidud0108 hey look at this site less workhttps://thrivethemes.com/quizbuilder/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is failing first of all but here is a suggestion or two 
Put each question in its own method chkQuestionOne() then in that method you know which two answers are correct so Boolean for ans1 if correct TRUE and same for other correct answer and FALSE for incorrect answer also at this time set int value for correct answer like this correctANS = 10; but correctANS need to be global declare it above the onCreate line of code int correctANS = 0; to keep a cumulative running score correctANS = correctANS + 10;
If you want instant feed back after each question I would need to write code for that sorry not that excited to do that. For a summary result at the end of the quiz more if statements like if(ans1 && ans2 selected) then both answers correct else test if only one correct and default if neither 1 and 2 selected NO CORRECT ANSWER if you like the idea and need more help I might try to write some code busy at this time

OK here is some real rough code it is not real complete one still busy and two if you have more than 10 questions we might suggest you use a sqlite DB to store the questions and possible answers then call the questions from the DB more than 10 questions and you are looking at a code management night mare WORD of warning I do not like the idea of setting the CheckBox to disabled like I said quick and dirty BOTH XML and MainActivity below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/color_lightGray"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.dwight.aquiz.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootRL"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Name 2 Cities in Ohio "
    android:textColor="@color/color_Black"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkqONEans1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="Canton"
    android:textColor="@color/color_Black"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkqTWOans2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="Akron"
    android:textColor="@color/color_Black"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkqTHREEans3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="Duluth"
    android:textColor="@color/color_Black"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnScore"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="SCORE"
    android:onClick="onScore"
    android:textColor="@color/color_Black"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etResult"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:textColor="@color/color_Black"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
   </LinearLayout>

package com.aquiz;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
CheckBox chkqONEans1;
CheckBox chkqTWOans2;
CheckBox chkqTHREEans3;
Button btnScore;
String stringqONEans1,stringqTWO1ans2,stringqTHREE1ans3,master;
EditText etResult;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    chkqONEans1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkqONEans1);
    chkqTWOans2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkqTWOans2);
    chkqTHREEans3= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkqTHREEans3);
    btnScore = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScore);
    etResult = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etResult);
}

public void onScore(View view){
    if( chkqONEans1.isChecked()){
        stringqONEans1 = "Correct Ans Canton";
        chkqONEans1.setEnabled(false);
    }
    if(chkqTWOans2.isChecked()){
        stringqTWO1ans2 = "Correct Ans Akron";
        chkqTWOans2.setEnabled(false);
    }
    if( chkqTHREEans3.isChecked()){
        stringqTHREE1ans3 = "INCORRECT Ans Duluth";
        chkqTHREEans3.setEnabled(false);
    }
    //if (chkqONEans1.isChecked() &&  chkqTWOans2.isChecked() && chkqTHREEans3.isChecked()){
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Only Two Answers", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //return;
    //}

    if( chkqONEans1.isEnabled()== false && chkqTWOans2.isEnabled()==false &&  chkqTHREEans3.isEnabled()==true){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Go On You Have Two Answers 1 & 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        master = "  " + stringqONEans1 +"\n  "+stringqTWO1ans2;
        showAns();

    }else if ( chkqONEans1.isEnabled()== false && chkqTWOans2.isEnabled()==true &&  chkqTHREEans3.isEnabled()==false){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Go On You Have Two Answers 1 & 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        master = stringqONEans1 +"  "+stringqTHREE1ans3;
        showAns();

    }else if ( chkqONEans1.isEnabled()== true && chkqTWOans2.isEnabled()==false &&  chkqTHREEans3.isEnabled()==false){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Go On You Have Two Answers 2 & 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       master = stringqTWO1ans2 +"  "+stringqTHREE1ans3;
        showAns();

    }else if( chkqONEans1.isEnabled()== false &&chkqTWOans2.isEnabled()== false && chkqTHREEans3.isEnabled()== false){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ONLY TWO Answers ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        chkqONEans1.setEnabled(true);
        chkqONEans1.setChecked(false);
        chkqTWOans2.setEnabled(true);
        chkqTWOans2.setChecked(false);
        chkqTHREEans3.setEnabled(true);
        chkqTHREEans3.setChecked(false);
        return;
    }
}

public void showAns(){
    etResult.setText(master);
}
```

}